# After upgrading to Plone 4.3 from 4.0.1 KeyError search_rss_enabled

Tags: plone

After a series of upgrades and migrations (the site was originally Plone 3 and them moved to 4, 4.1, 4.2 and now 4.3.3). I'm getting the following errors on some of the folders I visit for my site:

```
KeyError('Interface `Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.syndication.ISiteSyndicationSettings` defines a field `search_rss_enabled`, for which there is no record.',) (Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details: Interface `Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.syndication.ISiteSyndicationSettings` defines a field `search_rss_enabled`, for which there is no record.)
```

Comment: Seems like an upgrade step from plone 4.2 to 4.3 did not work, but it's strange since there's an upgrade step for exactly that in plone.app.upgrade (https://github.com/plone/plone.app.upgrade/blob/master/plone/app/upgrade/v43/alphas.py#L121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for some reason an upgrade step was missed, as pointed out by Mathias in his comment.

I had to force it to run by doing the following:

1. Go to ZMI > portal_setup ({site}/portal_setup/manage) > upgrade

   [image]
2. Then I selected all upgrade steps from 4300 (which included the
   syndication step) up to 4308 (the profile version that corresponds
   to 4.3.3)

   [image]

This fixed the error. I didn't try only running the syndication upgrade step because I figured there might have been other steps that had not been run. Thanks again Mathias, your comment helped to guide me to the solution.